# MiKTeX Problem: Couldn't resolve host name

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

I tried an update of my miktex2.9 on win 7, but started getting "Couldn't resolve host name" from MiKTeX Package Manager each time I tried installing a new package .
Can I seek your advice on how I should overcome this? Thank you in advanced.

Here is the log error when I try to instal new package :

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Couldn't resolve host name
Data: 
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\CurlWebSession.cpp
Line: 329
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit, Service Pack 1, build 7601
Invokers: explorer
SystemAdmin: yes
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\sanae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\sanae\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\sanae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\sanae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\sanae\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

Here is the log error when I try to update Wizard :

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
Data: 
Source: Programs\MiKTeX\PackageManager\MFC\MpmView.cpp
Line: 918
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit, Service Pack 1, build 7601
Invokers: explorer
SystemAdmin: yes
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\sanae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\sanae\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\sanae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\sanae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\sanae\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: Just in case: are you sure the compiler wasn't running (e.g.  waiting for some answer on the console) when you launched MPM or MiKTeX Update?

Comment: Yes i m sure nothing was running in my computer

Comment: Maybe try to change repository from MPM and synchronise.

Comment: it doesn't work, I still get the same error messages

Comment: Did you check your internet connection?

Comment: yes I did, nothing work , I even disable my firewall

Comment: Then  here is a workaround: download the packages you want to install from some repository to some directory on your system for instance with `FileZilla`, add these 4 files: `pr.ini`, `files.csv.lzma`, `miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma` and `miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma`. This being done, change repository to this local repository and install with MPM.

Comment: Nothing work , so i did uninstall MikTex from my computer along with TEXstudio, then I started from the beginning , that did work for my problem

Comment: I guess something went wrong at first installation.

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP solved it by reinstalling (see comments).

Answer (score 0):

Open the MikTex Package Manager and check the Repository configuration.

If you want to install from the Internet and are behind a proxy firewall, you will need to set the proxy server information. Choose the desired mirror to download packages from. If the mirror site is unavailable when you try to use it you may get an error and will need to change the repository location.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "set the proxy server information"?

Comment: I would like to know what that means too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your proxy settings in the connectivity if you are choosing to install the packages from internet.
After setting the proxy you need to give your proxy authentication.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While this may answer similar questions it does not answer the question in the OP (see comments). Furthermore it duplicates the other answer.